# Transform a list of files (JSON) to a dataframe

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

**Spark Version:** '2.0.0.2.5.0.0-1245'

---

So, my original question changed a bit but it's still the same issue.

What I want to do is load a huge amount of JSON files and transform those to a DataFrame - also probably save them as CSV or parquet file for further processing. Each JSON file represents one row in the final DataFrame.

```py
import os
import glob

HDFS_MOUNT = # ...
DATA_SET_BASE = # ...

schema = StructType([
        StructField("documentId", StringType(), True),
        StructField("group", StringType(), True),
        StructField("text", StringType(), True)     
])

# Get the file paths    
file_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(HDFS_MOUNT, DATA_SET_BASE, '**/*.json'))
file_paths = [f.replace(HDFS_MOUNT + '/', '') for f in file_paths]

print('Found {:d} files'.format(len(file_paths))) # 676 files

sql = SQLContext(sc)

df = sql.read.json(file_paths, schema=schema)

print('Loaded {:d} rows'.format(df.count())) # 9660 rows (what !?)
```

Besides the fact that there are 9660 rows instead of 676 (number of available files) I also have the problem that the content seems to be `None`:

```
df.head(2)[0].asDict()
```

gives

```
{
 'documentId': None,
 'group': None,
 'text': None,
}
```

---

## Example Data

This is just fake data of course but it resembles the actual data.

> **Note:** Some fields may be missing e.g. `text` must not always be present.

a.json

```
{
  "documentId" : "001",
  "group" : "A",
  "category" : "indexed_document",
  "linkIDs": ["adiojer", "asdi555", "1337"]
}
```

b.json

```
{
  "documentId" : "002",
  "group" : "B",
  "category" : "indexed_document",
  "linkIDs": ["linkId", "1000"],
  "text": "This is the text of this document"
}
```

Comment: does all the files has the same structure? And do they placed into one directory?

Comment: @IuriiNedostup Well, `RDBDocument.to_row` makes sure that each row has the same structure - I don't know if there is a better way to do this but each JSON represents basically one row in the the final data frame. Yes, the JSON files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that all your files has the same structure and are in the same directory:

```py
df = sql_cntx.read.json('/hdfs/path/to/folder/*.json')
```

There might be a problem if any of the columns has Null values for all rows. Then spark will not be able to determine schema, so you have an option to tell spark which schema to use:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType

sc = SparkContext(appName="My app")
sql_cntx = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("field1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("field2", LongType(), True)
])

df = sql_cntx.read.json('/hdfs/path/to/folder/*.json', schema=schema)
```

**UPD:** 
in case if file has multirows formatted json you can try this code:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName='Test') 
sql_context = SQLContext(sc) 

rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles('/tmp/test/*.json').values() 
df = sql_context.read.json(rdd, schema=schema)
df.show()
```

Comment: I see... well, yes... it may be because of null values. The only option I see right now is to read json headers, define schema and make dataframe.

Comment: could please post a couple of rows as an example?

Comment: I added two "sample files". It shows that e.g. `text` is not always present. All the fields should be `StringType`. I've tried to specify the schame but `df.head(1)[0].asDict()` returns all values to be `None` :/

Comment: I have now changed my original question a bit to where we are right now. Idk it's weird that the number of rows is e.g. different ..

Comment: quick question: can the file have many rows? how they are separated?

Comment: Well, yes they are "nicely" formatted - so they have multiple rows - is that a problem for `SqlContext.read.json`?

Comment: sorry, I meant multiple elements, i.e. many `documentId`s. and how they are separated(comma, or just new line). Depends on the spark version you have, but spark prefers if rows are not formatted: 1 row - 1 line. But for spark >= 2.2.x there is an option to read multi lines formatted rows

Comment: Oh, now that you ask that .. I took a closer look - apparently some fields are actually of type `list` .. That means I'll have to transform the data at first ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164974/discussion-between-iurii-nedostup-and-displayname).